# How to reference the files in the Files section from Code/Pascal section?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

In my code section I need to modify an existing configuration file (Apache `httpd.conf`) to include one of the files I'm installing in the `Files` section.

How can I reference my `.conf` file, so I can insert into the `httpd.conf` something like this:

```
Include "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/conf/myinclude.conf"
```

I think I can do something like:

```pascal
 ExtractFilePath( {app} ) + '\conf\myinclude.conf'
```

to get the full path of the file.

However that means I have to hard code the partial path in my script code. If we later change the path then I have to change it in the files section and remember to change it in the script code too.

Is there a way to reference the file just by name and get the full installed path?

Secondary question:
What's the best place to do this kind of thing (modifying a file)?

1. In the `AfterInstall` of the file I'm going to modify it for?
2. In `NextButtonClick` on `wpFinished`?
3. Other?

Comment: I suppose I could define a variable for the partial path and use that everywhere - that would resolve the issue of having to change it in multiple places. However I'm still new to INNO so not sure if I can get a variable to expand everywhere I might need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [preprocessor constant/variable](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=define).

The best place to update the `httpd.conf` is [`CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged). The `AfterInstall` will do too.

```pascal
#define MyIncludeName "myinclude.conf"
#define MyIncludeRelPath "conf\" + MyIncludeName

[Files]
Source: "{#MyIncludeName}"; DestDir: "{app}\..\{#MyIncludeRelPath}"

[Code]

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  Path: string;
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    Path := ExtractFilePath(ExpandConstant('{app}')) + '{#MyIncludeRelPath}';
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! 
It would be nice if the files in the files section could be named or given an ID that you could reference, but this is a workable solution.